# Rancher-Desktop: "docker: 'scout' is not a docker command."

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, rancher-desktop

I am using Rancher-Desktop and get the following error when I try to analyse docker images for vulnerabilities locally with `docker scout cves fs://.`

```bash
docker: 'scout' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

Is the `docker scout` part of Docker-Desktop only? Can I use `docker scout` with Rancher-Desktop as e.g. plugin, extension etc, similar to other docker commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Scout is packaged with Docker Desktop. You can install it separately following [Docker's instructions](https://docs.docker.com/scout/install/):

```bash
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/scout-cli/main/install.sh -o install-scout.sh
sh install-scout.sh
```

Comment: The Docker Scout CLI license: https://github.com/docker/scout-cli?tab=readme-ov-file#license